# Extract multiple paragraphs from text string after they match a pattern with R

Tags: r, string, tidyr

I  have a data frame with one column `text` as strings of interview transcripts between two people.

The format is firstname lastname m:ss then a line break, a paragraph of text, a line break, then firstname lastname m:ss a line break and a paragraph of text as below.

```
John Smith 2:03
Is this great?
Joe Blogs 2:24
Yes it is.
John Smith 2:35
Is it the greatest of all time?
Joe Blogs 2:47
Clearly.
```

I want to make 2 new strings to go in two new columns in my df. One for each person containing the paragraphs of text after their names strung together.

The interviewer in each of the text files is one of two people so I could match their name to assign them to an ‘interviewer”. I also have the interviewer name in an `interviewer` column of the df already.

Interviewer names: John Smith, Jane Doe

Desired Output:

| interviewer | subject |
| --- | --- |
| Is this great? Is it the greatest of all time? | Yes it is. Clearly. |

I'm not sure the best way to achieve what I am after. I've used tidyr extract to the interviewer, date etc. from the file names to put them into columns in my dataframe, but am not experienced enough to know how to use it to split the text like this - or if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: does the interviewer text always end with "?" ? how do you know the difference between interviewer and  subject?

Comment: No - it doesn't always end with a ? I know the name of the interviewer and there's a timestamp. I've tried a tidyr extract by matching the interviewer name and the timestamp pattern, but don't know how to get more than the first match to string together.

Comment: Is the order always this way?

Comment: No, the subject might speak before the interviewer which is why it might be best to match on the interviewer name.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** A string independent version:

```
df %>%
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 0) %>% 
  group_by(x = rep(c("subject", "interviewer"), length.out = n())) %>% 
  mutate(text = paste(text, collapse = " ")) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 0) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = text)
```

```
 subject                                        interviewer        
  <chr>                                          <chr>              
1 Is this great? Is it the greatest of all time? Yes it is. Clearly.
```

**First answer:**
We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(text, '\\.|\\?')) %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(str_detect(text, '\\.'), "subject", "interviewer")) %>% 
  arrange(x) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(text = paste(text, collapse = " ")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = text)
```

```
 interviewer                                    subject            
  <chr>                                          <chr>              
1 Is this great? Is it the greatest of all time? Yes it is. Clearly.
```